# la plantilla admin lte no me carga cuando le incluyo el modulo de código para mostrar los datos de la base de datos

Tags: php

lo que pasa es que estoy trabajando con la plantilla de admin lte con php y ahora que estoy haciendo la vista no me quiere cargar la pagina, simplemente se queda hay y no hace nada cuando le pongo el código de la vista o cuando lo incluyo. lo he intentado de todas las formas posibles pero realmente me ha quedado muy complejo y no se porque sea. les agradecería que me ayudaran a continuación les muestro un poco el problema.

Comment: Es muy difícil ayudar sin un [repro]. Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.